# Change the output name when download with youtube-dl using python

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I tried to follow the tutorial to download a video from youtube:

```
import youtube_dl
ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bdf-PSJpccM'])
```

But i see only when using the command(in command line) with option `-o` we can change the output video name. So, how to add change output name option embedded in python script?
I think it should be add to `ydl_opts`, but i don't know the syntax, can anybody help?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try like this:

```
import youtube_dl
ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': 'file_path/file_name'}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bdf-PSJpccM'])
```

Substitute the desired filename and filepath in ydl_opts. `file_path/file_name`

Comment: Btw, can you give me the link of the doc talk about function syntax?

Comment: @AlphaWolf It was right there from where you picked the example. https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L128-L278

Answer (score 1):

Just complementing @MYGz answer, the `outtmpl` can be formatted according to the video data. You can get more information here: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/5192#issuecomment-78843396.