# set path and url of youtube file downloader at run time by user

Tags: python, wxpython, urllib, shutil, youtube-dl

below is the code for downloading youtube files providing URL, but at present the URL is static, I'm trying to make it dynamic so that user can put URL at runtime. and secondly, I'm also trying to set the path where to save, file by the user but, somehow not able to do

(I'm working on python3 idle with windows)

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
import urllib
import shutil
ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://youtu.be/zhWDdy_5v2w'])
print("DONE!")
```

Comment: For dynamic options you can provide command line options to the script for example, scriptName url_of_file and for the second part of the question, you can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240726/change-the-output-name-when-download-with-youtube-dl-using-python

Comment: didn't get it correctly, I tried to set the path but it just didn't work the way i want

Comment: but that at a static value, i want the URL to be set by user at runtime

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should work:

```js
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import sys
import youtube_dl
import urllib
import shutil
ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': '~/Documents/file_name'}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
  ydl.download(sys.argv[1:])
print("DONE!")
```

Usage: `youtube_script.py youtube_url`

You can use it like this . Though I have not tested the code but it should work. If i correctly understand, you mean the user can set the url when starting the python script ?, then this is how it should be done or you can take the input in a string and then provide it to the ydl.download function.

Comment: thanx, a lot it somehow sort my concept, but it works on command line, and I'm using python 3 idle

Comment: @monikarazdan Your welcome :), If it works fine, mark it as the correct answer or update my answer if you get it working, in case i have missed something.

Comment: it has some errors, but will sort and update soon and let you know @hassanabbas